# Edit settimeout on autofill javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, autofill

I want to place a command that allows me to change the waiting time after the click, for example

```js
var myVar;
    
function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
}

function alertFunc() {
  alert("Hello!");
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

### [Plunkr Example with enhanced code](http://plnkr.co/edit/iK5pVnzBcdlJn4RBm5J8?p=preview)

**JS**

```
// Code goes here

var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  // this is to make sure we don't spin up infinite timeouts and have zombie threads
  if(myVar === undefined) {
    myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
  } else {
    alert("already running...");
  }
}

function alertFunc() {
  alert("hello!");
  // clears the thread
  clearTimeout(myVar);
  myVar = undefined;
}
```

---

### Your Code

Your code seems to be working just fine, `alert` will work when not in the stack overflow sandbox and the only thing I added was clearing the timeout with `clearTimeout` this is so it doesn't continually run infinitely.

```js
var myVar;
    
function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
}

function alertFunc() {
  console.log("Hello!");
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved with jQuery.

```
$(".my-button").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("hello");
   }, 3000);
})
```

Comment: unless the OP specifies jQuery it is best to not recommend it as the answer.